# ajax request keeps returning last request

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get ajax to return images for a internal gallery. I have it returning the images I want, the only problem is that the returned images is one request behind.

E.g. If I called `return_img("test", 1, 5)` no images are returned but when I call `return_img("test", 6, 10)` images 1 to 5 form the test album are returned.

My javascript code

```
function return_img(album, start, end) {
    vars = "album" + album + "&start=" + start + "&end=" + end;
    _("out").innerHTML = "";

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "gallery_return_img.php", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            var returned = request.responseText;
            returned = JSON.parse(returned);
            for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(returned).length; i++) {
                x = document.createElement("div");
                y = document.createElement("img");
                y.setAttribute("src", returned[i].url);
                x.appendChild(y);
                document.getElementById("out").appendChild(x);
            }
        }
    };
    request.send(vars);
}
```

My PHP code

```
if (key_exists('album', $_POST) && key_exists('start', $_POST) && key_exists('end', $_POST)) {
    $album = $_POST['album'];
    $start = $_POST['start'];
    $end = $_POST['end'];
    $render = json_decode(file_get_contents("/gallery_images/$album/info.pics"));
    $total = count($render);
    if($end > $total){
        $end = $total;
    }
    $pictures = [];
    for($start; $start <= $end; $start++) {
        array_push($pictures, $render[$start]);
    }
}
```

The info.pics file contains a JSON encoded list of the URLs and image names need to render the images in that album.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that programming issues should be asked on [so]. For more information on our site, see our [tour].

Comment: `no images are returned` - check the browsers **developer** tools console to check what the request returns - note: your PHP code looks like it never sends anything, as there is nothing output by that code

Comment: I'm guessing (it's hard to tell from the code that you've posted) that the server side element takes a little to process and it simply appears that it's processing the previous request due to the delay. As @JaromandaX your network tab should make this obvious.

Comment: your javascript for loop looks odd, fortunately your PHP looks like it will return an array, so the code won't break into a million pieces :p also, `vars = "album" + album` looks wrong

Comment: The network tab confirms that I am sending off the correct request and get back the correct response.

Comment: Has for the PHP code that was bad copying of code on my part. Should of been  `for($start; $start <= $end; $start++){ array_push($pictures, $render[$start]);}$pictures = json_encode($pictures);echo $pictures;}`

Comment: Again sorry bad copping on my part `vars = "album=" + album`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Half stumbled across the problem after rereading the a XMLHttpRequest() syntax.

Asynchronous is set to true.

```
request.open("POST", "gallery_return_img.php", true);
```

I set it to false and no more problem.

```
request.open("POST", "gallery_return_img.php", false);
```

Don't quite understand why this makes a difference but it works.